# Put Block list Forbidden Azure

Tags: c#, rest, azure, httpclient, azure-blob-storage

I'am quiet new in Azure, and I'm trying to implement the `Put Block List` operation according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list).
Here are the steps, which I do to upload my file

1. Read a file from a local folder
2. Upload it using [`Put block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) operation. it gets succes.
3. Then I use 
   [`Get Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-block-list) to see if my blocks are uploaded and in the response I can see

```js
<BlockList><CommittedBlocks /><UncommittedBlocks><Block><Name>MDAwMDAwMDAwMA==</Name><Size>17</Size></Block></UncommittedBlocks></BlockList>
```

that I have one `uncommited` block with ID `MDAwMDAwMDAwMA==`.

4. And finally I use `Put Block List` to commit the blob.
   Here I get an error code 403 "Forbidden".

My Signature is the following

```
"PUT\n
\n
\n
110\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
x-ms-date:Tue, 15 May 2018 10:54:08 GMT\nx-ms-version:2017-07-29\n
/storagekaren/dbstore/ddd.txt\ncomp:blocklist"
```

Here is the uri

```
https://storagekaren.blob.core.windows.net/dbstore/ddd.txt?comp=blocklist
```

request content

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"? 
>\r\n<BlockList>\r\n<Uncommitted>MDAwMDAwMDAwMA==</Uncommitted> 
</BlockList>\r\n"
```

authorizationHeader is computed using this method

```
public static String CreateAuthorizationHeader(String canonicalizedString)
    {
        string signature;

        using (var hmacSha256 = new         
HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY)))
        {
            var dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedString);
            signature = 
Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
        }

        var authorizationHeader = String.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1}:{2}",
            "SharedKey",
            ACCOUNT_NAME,
            signature
        );

        return authorizationHeader;
    }

"SharedKey storagekaren:eIHacFz/PWypTWg6SN/4BOuqlCLVLctABhi6Ay7TYiA="
```

And this is my HttpClient object to make a request

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpClient}
    BaseAddress: null
    DefaultRequestHeaders: {x-ms-date: Tue, 15 May 2018 11:07:51 GMT
x-ms-version: 2017-07-29
Authorization: SharedKey     storagekaren:eIHacFz/PWypTWg6SN/4BOuqlCLVLctABhi6Ay7TYiA=
}
    MaxResponseContentBufferSize: 2147483647
    Timeout: {01:00:00}
```

Here is the response with error

```js
HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value         
of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
Content-Length: 686
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 7a96deee-201e-00fc-78de-ec0ffc000000
x-ms-error-code: AuthenticationFailed
Date: Wed, 16 May 2018 06:22:35 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error>    
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the 
request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly 
including the signature.
RequestId:7a96deee-201e-00fc-78de-ec0ffc000000
Time:2018-05-16T06:22:36.0842958Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The 
MAC signature found in the HTTP request 
'E9M4w8nHaBbAsgW3Qhf+u5nHipvmxMvLp09AFdaxYZg=' is not the same as any 
computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT


110

text/plain






x-ms-date:Wed, 16 May 2018 06:22:34 GMT
x-ms-version:2017-07-29
/storagekaren/dbstore/ddd.txt
comp:blocklist'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used your actual storage account key in authorization header? If that’s the case, please change it immediately. You’ll need to compute authorization header. Please share the code for that.

Comment: No. it's not the actual key, it is computed Using HMACSHA256 Base64 encoding. I've shared the code as you said

Comment: I don't see `Content-Length` header in your `DefaultRequestHeaders`. Not sure if it gets added automatically. Can you edit your question and include more details about the error. I'm guessing there's a slight mismatch in your signature string and the one created on the server side. Error message will include the string used by the server.

Comment: `Content-Length` is added in `content.Headers` and don't need to be added to `DefaultRequestHeaders`,The error details are added in the question. But I also want to notice, this sginature works for `Put Block` operation which is more confusing for me.Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question and providing error details. I think I know why you're getting this error. Let me provide an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the problem is coming because `HttpClient` is adding `text/plain` for `Content-Type` header whereas you're passing an empty string for that. If you change your signature string to include content-type header, I believe you should not get this error. Essentially, your signature string should look like the following:

```
"PUT\n
\n
\n
110\n
\n
text/plain\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
x-ms-date:Tue, 15 May 2018 10:54:08 GMT\nx-ms-version:2017-07-29\n
/storagekaren/dbstore/ddd.txt\ncomp:blocklist"
```